# how to play video on click in android without using play button icon in JW player

Tags: android, jwplayer

I want to play and stop video on click on video after hiding the JW player controls of Play and stop button icon.
How can I do that.

Comment: Hi, post your current java code and also xml layout file for better understanding your current state. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Android SDK?  In that case you can create a button that is displayed above the JWPlayer, and respond to the touch events on that button to perform a play.